# How to filter or query list of index names in Elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch, wildcard

I use the following to list indices

```
curl localhost:9200/_cat/indices?v
```

Is there is any way to filter or query index names, for example like with wildcards?

```
curl localhost:9200/_cat/indices - d '{
  "query": {
    "prefix": {
      "index": "sam-"
    }
  }
}'
```

What would be the format in elasticsearch.js?

Answer (score 31):

Simple: `curl localhost:9200/_cat/indices/sam-*?v`

Comment: I found this question because I was looking for the same thing.  This answer isn't good enough though - I want to be able to combine index queries with other queries.  i.e. "color is red and index starts with colors or size is large and index starts with sizes".  Is there some way to do what OP asked?

Comment: @Julian post your question on SO and I might be able to help you.

Comment: Maybe you could amend your answer here, where the question is already asked.  Anyway, I think I found the answer: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-index-field.html

Comment: @Julian that's the answer, yes, but the initial question in this post is about something else that's why this is not the best post to provide the answer.

Comment: I see what you mean, this Q is about filtering the list of indexes rather than limiting query results to particular index contents.

Answer (score 0):

It should be like that:

```
curl -X GET "127.0.0.1:9200/_cat/indices/sam-*?v&s=index"
```